# Initialization of an inferred closure argument

Tags: rust

I want to find a way to initialize a Rust struct and pass it to an `Fn(T)` closure as the only parameter. However, I want to infer the type of the struct (`T`) from the closure.

So the invocation `call_with_props!(my_closure, id, 42);` should expand to `my_closure(T {id: 42});` or equivalent, where `T` is the type of the only argument of `my_closure`. (I'm not necessarily looking for a macro-based solution though.)

```rs
struct A { id: i32 }
fn hello_1(props: A) { println!("hello {}", props.id); }

struct B { name: String }
fn hello_2(props: B) { println!("hi {}", props.name); }

macro_rules! call_with_props {
    // <------------------------------- What comes here?
}

fn main() {
    call_with_props!(hello_1, id, 42);
    // Should expand to: hello_1(A{id: 42}); 

    call_with_props!(hello_2, name, String::new("Bob"));
    // Should expand to: hello_2(B{name: String::new("Bob")}); 
}
```

Comment: Have you read about macros in [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html) or other resources? Have you attempted any solutions yourself and encountered a stumbling block?

Comment: What you want isn't really clear (why pass "hello1" to the macro if the type shoud be detected from the type of argument ?). Overall it looks like what you need is just to define a trait and add implementations for i32 and String.

Comment: @user4815162342 I've read the documentation including the tlborm, and it's still unclear to me whether it's possible or not. The stumbling block for me is that Rust only allows named struct initialization, so `hello_1({id: 42})` won't fly even though the compiler should have enough information to figure out what needs to be done.

Comment: Macros are evaluated before normal compilation, so types are still unknown. There's no way to "get the type of the argument" with a macro.

Comment: @Aplet123 Thanks. I experimented with generics to solve this problem, but I couldn't infer a type I could use like that. I hoped some combination of macros and templates could get me there.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Thank you. I prefer a solution where I don't need to define additional traits. But I'm mostly just trying to learn what's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can add `#[derive(Default)]` to your structs, then this works:

```
// Create an instance of `T` and invoke a closure to initialize its fields.
// Allows creating a `T` without naming it, provided it is used in a context
// that accepts a concrete type. For example:
//
// hello_1(init(Default::default(), |v| v.id = 42));
fn init<T: Default>(mut v: T, f: impl FnOnce(&mut T)) -> T {
    f(&mut v);
    v
}

macro_rules! call_with_props {
    ($f: path, $($name: ident, $value: expr),+) => {{
        $f(init(Default::default(), |v| {
            $(v.$name = $value;)*
        }))
    }}
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3c7a0e720354d7c6f8f49de2cff7410f)